# Slick - This DBMS allows only a single AutoInc column to be returned from an INSERT

Tags: slick

In Slick, some [examples](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.0/queries.html#upserting) throw this exception.

```
slick.SlickException: This DBMS allows only a single column to be returned from an INSERT, and that column must be an AutoInc column.
```

Which DBMS do support this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres and Oracle support `returning` with multiple columns.

Mysql does not support it, but slick probably emulates it for auto increment ids with the `last_insert_id()` call.

Not sure if any others support it.
(They should add this to the documentation..)